# ffmpeg formats which allow freq above 18khz

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, codec

Can anyone suggest me what **audio and video codecs** allows me to retain frequencies above 18khz till 22050hz in the resultant mp4 or avi video with out any filters.

No limit for size and HD is preferred.

Comment: Although there are other variables, the key factor is to make sure the sample rate is more than twice the highest frequency you want to preserve.

Comment: yeah I made sure sampling rate is 44100+, even then i couldnt find any frequency above 16khz in the resultant Mp4's audio

Answer (score 1):

AAC encoders supports frequencies up to 96000 Hz. ("libfdk_aac", "aac", "libvo_aacenc" codecs)

**UPD**

I took a lossless compressed audio as the source.

See its spectrum

[image: Source spectrum]

I recoded it with the video using ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg -t 10 -i 01.mp4 -t 10 -i Wait.m4a -ar 48000 -ab 320k -c:a aac -strict -2 Wait.mp4`

The spectrum of the audio in the resulting file.

[image]

Comment: but when I use $ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:a libfdk_aac out.mp4 the resultant video doesnt contain any freq greater than 16Khz

Comment: Try `$ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -sample_rate 96000 out.mp4`

Comment: No its dint work pogorskiy. Freq got cut off at 16k

Comment: If you're talking about cutting the frequency you may be sure that the original audio has a larger range.

Comment: Yeah am very sure that original audio file has freq till 20khz. I use spek to get the spectrum.

Comment: 1. I wrote wrong setting (sample_rate), use `-ar 96000` options instead. 2. Try to increase audio bitrate (`-ab 360k`) 3. Most players will not play files with a high sampling rate, so use `-ar 48000`.

Comment: Used your setting and still i face the same problem.Is it the problem with video that cant hold audio in its container?

Comment: see update in my answer